# Proving the existence of good covers

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

Usually one proves the existence of good covers in compact manifolds by Riemannian methods: we pick an arbitrary Riemannian metric, prove that geodesically convex neighborhoods exist, that they are closed under finite intersections, and diffeomorphic to balls; this is, for example, the argument that Bott and Tu sketch in their book.

> Is there a non-Riemannian approach to this?

While this is not necessary for most things, it is a nice fact that good covers can be found which realize the covering dimension bound.

> Is there a differential-topological way to find them?

Comment: (I am writing notes on de Rham cohomology, would love to have good covers available, but would much prefer to avoid to go through the Riemannian detour...)

Comment: Interesting question. Small comment: the Riemannian argument does not use compactness, but of course it guarantees existence of a *finite* good cover (in Bott&Tu's terminolgy).

Answer (score 22):

you don't really need a whole lot of Riemannian geometry to prove this. Embed the manifold into $\mathbb R^n$ by Whitney and look at very small charts around points given by orthogonal projections onto the tangent spaces. the transition maps will be arbitrary close to identity in $C^2$. that means that a small round disk in one chart will remain strictly convex in nearby charts (because if $f(x)=|x|^2$ and $\phi$ is a transition map  such that $\phi-Id$ has small first and second derivatives then $f\circ \phi$ is still strictly convex and hence has convex sublevel sets). This is is all you need to conclude that all intersections are contractible. I guess since the above argument doesn't use any Riemannian geometry notions it should qualify as an answer to  the second question?

Incidentally, does a good open cover always exist if a manifold is only topological?

Comment: Can I ask you to give  an independent question consists your last statement?

Comment: This proof can also be found in Andre Weil's paper pages 120-122 Sur les Theoremes de de Rham Comm.Math.Helvetici vol 26 pages 119-145

Answer (score 7):

The answer to both questions is yes.  Fix a triangulation of the manifold. For any vertex $v$ denote by $U_v$ the union of the relative interiors of all the faces of all dimensions that contain the vertex $v$. (Note: the vertex $v$ itself is a  face containing $v$  and it coincides with its relative interior.)  The set $U_v$ is open and contractible  and the resulting open cover is good. Its nerve is  is the simplicial set underlying the chosen triangulation.   This cover answers both your questions.

Comment: Heh. COnstructing a triangulation from knowledge of a smooth structure alone is a longer detour, no?

Comment: H. Whitney describes a simple triangulation procedure in his book *Geometric integration theory*.  In  the book   by Singer & Thorpe *Lecture Notes on Elementary  Topology and Geometry* they   prove that DeRham cohomology is isomorphic to singular homology using triangulations and the  trick I mentioned. There they work on triagulable manifolds to avoid the theorem about  existence of traingulations. On the subject of DeRham theorem see also the undergraduate thesis below. 

http://www.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Fanoethesis.pdf

Comment: Ah, good! I'll look in Whitney's book. Thanks!

Comment: A caveat: the procedure is simple, but the proof that it produces a triangulation is quite involved.  Here is the procedure: embed the manifold in some vector space, choose a generic  basis  $(\xi_k)$ of the dual space and then look at the  intersection of the submanifold with the  hyperplanes $\xi_k\in \varepsilon\mathbb{Z}$.  For $\varepsilon$ small these hyperplanes    trace along the submanifold a polyhedral decomposition. This can be easily transformed  into a triangulation.  The hard part is to show that this procedure yields the promised polyhedral decomposition.

Comment: That's close to what my intuition wanted to do: embed the manifold in a vector space (I have already proved this is possible in the compact case in my notes, so this is fine :) ) and intersect it with balls... and magically prove that when the radius is small the resulting covering is good. 

Comment: S.Cairns has a 2-page proof of triangulability of smooth manifolds in "A simple triangulation method for smooth manifolds," Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 67 (1961), 389-390. 

Comment: @Misha: Thnks for the reference. @Mariano:  This is roughly Whitney's strategy but instead of small balls he uses  small cubes coming from a coordinate grid. Realizing the covering dimension bound takes a bit more work.

Comment: Nothing in the original question says that the manifold is smooth or triangulable.

Comment: @Greg: Given the author's stated  interest in DeRham cohomology, smoothness is a reasonable assumption. 



Comment: @Misha  The two page triangulation proof by Cairns (1961) is flawed: see more discussion here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/139339/voronoi-cells-and-the-dual-complexes-in-riemannian-manifolds/177199#177199

Comment: @Ramsay: Thank you, I will take a look.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can obtain a good cover of $C^2$ manifold (compact or not) from the charts/atlas definition and a little bit of topology (locally finite atlas and a relatively compact "shrinking" of it).

The very simple idea (akin to that in Vitali's answer) is that under a $C^2$ diffeomorphism between open subsets of euclidean $n$-space, the (pre-)image of a sufficiently small ball centered at a point will be convex, as soon as the curvature of its boundary "dominates" the second derivative of the diffeomorphism (or its inverse).

In formulas, if $\phi$ is the diffeomorphism, this boils down to the fact that the $C^2$ function $x\mapsto |\phi(x)-\phi(x_0)|^2$ has a positive definite hessian at $x_0$, hence is convex near $x_0$.

With a little more care, I think you can still conclude if $\phi$ is only $C^{1+Lip}$.

Comment: I think Mariano might object to using curvature explanations as being too Riemannian  but the argument using convexity of the composite function (which was what I had in mind all along) doesn't formally use it although it  of course amounts the same thing.

Comment: Yes, this is essentially the same idea as yours, only replacing projections on tangent spaces by zooms of local charts, observing that zooming a $C^2$ diffeomorphism makes it look more and more linear. I think the main point is this avoids Whitney embedding (admittedly not so hard), and can be proved from the very definition of manifold.

Comment: you are quite right and even Whitney is not needed for this.

Comment: This proof is in Demailly's book Complex Algebraic and Differential Geometry.